Typescript output directory setup
I need help to set up my tsconfig.json file.
I'm building a Django project with multiple apps, the base structure for what I would like to obtain is as follows:
project/
      |-app1/
      |
      |-app2/
      |
      |-tsconfig.js

Now, each app folder should have this structure:
appX/
   |-static/
          |-appX
               |-js/
               |  |-test.js
               |
               |-ts/
                  |-test.ts

Basically, I want my tsconfig to output the relative JS file always inside "../js/", and this has to be true for any app of the project. Is this possible to achieve?
I have tried to change outDir, but I can't build it so that it takes into consideration a generic relative path. For example, using ../js simply creates the JavaScript files inside a folder on the same level as "project"

fyi I rolled back the last edit, as it introduced typos and added an unneeded tag.
